# the async callback can't get external parameters

Tags: node.js, express

[the 25 line can get value, however when I 'data.name' is undefined,  I had not an idea, someone help me? thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/546pj.png)

Comment: It's better if you can paste you code as code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things which are going wrong in your code

1. `fs.readFile` returns the content of the file as `string` so you need to first parse the content if contents are `JSON` and then you can access the keys and values in it
2. You are accessing `name` in `data` which is not available in JSON object. You have to mention key name stored in variable by passing it in square brackets rather than `dot(.)` operator like `data[name]`

Attaching code for reference:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function find(name,  cb){
        fs.readFile('./db.json', 'utf8', function(err, data){
                if(err) return cb(err)
                data =  JSON.parse(data);
                cb(null, data[name]);
        });
}

find('student', function(err, data){
        console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: You are trying to access data[name] directly where as data contains student array object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your object structure, `data` is an array of objects, so you'll have to access like `data.student[i].name`; here `i` is some index

`data.student[0].name // prints 'tom'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.student[0].name`?